# How can I make use a powershell command to replace a string witha new line? From within a batch file? -double quotes issue

Tags: powershell, batch-file, replace, double-quotes

The desired output is to convert all of the 5 tildes into a new line character.

The command is

```
Powershell (Get-Content -Raw allactsconv.txt) "-replace '~~~~~', "[\r\n]" | Out-File -FilePath allactsconv.txt -Force -Encoding ascii"
```

It returns

```
    At line:1 char:55
+ (Get-Content -Raw allactsconv.txt) -replace '~~~~~', [\r\n] | Out-Fil ...
+                                                       ~
Missing type name after '['.
At line:1 char:53
+ (Get-Content -Raw allactsconv.txt) -replace '~~~~~', [\r\n] | Out-Fil ...
+                                                     ~
Missing expression after ','.
At line:1 char:54
+ (Get-Content -Raw allactsconv.txt) -replace '~~~~~', [\r\n] | Out-Fil ...
+                                                      ~~~~~~
Unexpected token '[\r\n]' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingTypename
```

I thought the problem might be the square brackets but the error is exactly the same without them.

The better solution would be to rewrite the entire batch file (it does a lot of other stuff) as a powershell script, but unfortunately I need to fix this now. At some point I will do that.

It looks like the problem is the double quotes within the double quotes, but how do I fix that? Would like to use a powershell command if I can as I need to learn it.

Comment: Is this a `powershell.exe -c` command? I don't get why you have `"-replace` there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based purely upon the strings you've indicated you want to replace and wish to replace them with, I'd offer the following options:

```sh
Powershell -NoProfile "(Get-Content -Raw \".\allactsconv.txt\") -Replace \"~~~~~\", \"[`r`n]\" | Out-File -FilePath \".\allactsconv.txt\" -Force -Encoding ASCII"
```

If you prefer to use single quotes, in PowerShell, *(not my preference)*, then:

```sh
Powershell -NoProfile "(Get-Content -Raw '.\allactsconv.txt') -Replace '~~~~~', '[`r`n]' | Out-File -FilePath '.\allactsconv.txt' -Force -Encoding ASCII"
```